# jquery function for showing default text after clear filter results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have custom filtering jQuery, the function is when the checkbox was checked it showing the rel value from the checkbox on div with class filter.

Meanwhile the div filter has default text write "Please choose".

What I need is when someone chooses the checkbox and then clicks the "Clear all" button it will clear the checked value, but at current state the default text from div filter "Please choose" does not appear again after clearing result.

Here is the Html code:

```
<div class="check">
<label><input type="checkbox" rel="A" name="A"/>a</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" rel="B" name="B"/>b</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" rel="C" name="C"/>c</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" rel="D" name="D"/>d</label>
<button class="clear -filter"onclick="$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');            
$('.results > div').show();                                                      
$('.textTrigger').html('');" type="reset" value="Clear all">Clear all</button>
</div>

<div class="filter">
  <p class="textTrigger">Please choose</p>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$('div.check').delegate('input[type="checkbox"]', 'change', function()
{
  var $lis = $('.results > div'),
  $checked = $('input:checked');

  var rels = [];
  $checked.each(function()
  {
        rels.push($(this).attr('name'));
  });
  $('.textTrigger').html(rels.join(', '));

  if ($checked.length)
  {
        var selector = $checked.map(function()
        {
              return '.' + $(this).attr('rel');
        }).get().join('');

        $lis.hide().filter(selector).show();
  }
  else
  {
        $lis.show();
  }
  });
```

And this is the link to fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nucleo1985/LugPX/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get rid of the `onclick` attribute on the button, it's not clean code. You're already using jQuery so I suggest you stick to that and move the JS logic away from inside the DOM element
2. Also use the [$.fn.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function instead of `delegate`

And use this ..

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
    $('.results > div').show();
    $('.textTrigger').html('Please choose');
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/A9Be9/)

Comment: ahhh, my error. Forgetting the little function on click because inline js inside button. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would, but my reputation still below 15 cant vote yet. May i ask another question?

Comment: You don't have to upvote, you can just accept it now and then upvote if you will late

Comment: ahh, done there. anyway, how to limiting the checkbox ? like 5 or 6 check per user?

Comment: You might have to ask that as a new question and explain it in detail. You have users involved, that seems like a bigger scope :)

Comment: let me know when you've asked it and I'll give it a go

Comment: Should i open new question now? thanks a lot for your time @dcodesmith

Comment: Yes you can @EricoAugustin